# getting a mystic non-class type error (must be simple)

Tags: c++

Right so I got this other error that is puzzling me... What I want to do is to add the real parts and Imaginary parts of two complex numbers, Im getting an error message when Im calling the disp().

main fine:

```
   #include <iostream>
#include "imaginary.h"


using namespace std;

int main()
{
int ImNum,ReNum,ImNum2,ReNum2;


cout<<"please provide the FIRST Imaginary number: ";
cin>>ImNum;
cout<<"please provide the SECOND Imaginary number: ";
cin>>ImNum2;
cout<<"please provide the FIRST Real number: ";
cin>>ReNum;
cout<<"please provide the SECOND Real number: ";
cin>>ReNum2;

imaginary addition(int ImNum, int ReNum, int ImNum2, int ReNum2);
addition.disp();
return 0;
}
```

Constructor file:

```
#include<iostream>
#include "imaginary.h"

using namespace std;


imaginary::imaginary(int ImNum, int ReNum, int ImNum2, int ReNum2):
    Im(ImNum), Re(ReNum), Im2(ImNum2), Re2(ReNum2)
{
}

int imaginary::sumIm(){return (Im+Im2);}
int imaginary::sumRe(){return (Re+Re2);}
void imaginary::disp(){
    std::cout<< " The student named: ";
    }
```

I know that the disp() does not display what I whant but that I will fix later.The error I get is as follows:

```
error: request for member 'disp' in 'addition', which is of non-class type 'imaginary(int, int, int, int)'
```

Any hints:

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: `imaginary addition(int ImNum, int ReNum, int ImNum2, int ReNum2);` should be `imaginary addition(ImNum, ReNum, ImNum2, ReNum2);`.

Comment: and `imaginary.h`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To call a constructor, only mention the names of the arguments. The list `int ImNum, int ReNum`… *declares* parameters, which in turn causes `addition` to be declared as a function instead of a variable.

You want:

```
imaginary addition(ImNum, ReNum, ImNum2, ReNum2);
```